# Float right, push left content down

Tags: html, css

I'm floating the SVG's to the right. I Would like these to be the uppermost objects and push the rest of the content down. The headers and paragraph should be pushed below the centeredmenu. Please enlighten me how i could accomplish this. I'm new to all this.

In the html, the menu and SVG's come first. That's no longer true after applying the CSS. Since i'm floating the SVG's to the right it seems to free up space to the left of the SVG that the header/paragraph claims for some reason. What makes it even weirder in my head is that it bypasses the menu as well.

I don't want to have to use clear:both on paragraphs and headers and everything else below as well. Would appreciate any other helpful comments as well. Thanks!

Not sure which code to include below... The fiddle will probably be alot more useful.
http://jsfiddle.net/akLQk/2/

```
svg {
float:right;
}
```

Comment: you don't have to use clear:both on all the divs following your svg divs, just one div will do..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also wrap the SVG and nav menus in a div, then in your CSS do this:

```
yourDivWrapper { overflow: auto; }
```

I have done so here: http://jsfiddle.net/joelisadev/StPky/

Answer (score 5):

Try adding this after all your svg content:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

It will push down all your other content. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Well, it definately works :) But isn't adding another div just for this purpose bad practice? Anyway, thank you!

Comment: hmmm your alternative would be to add a clear property to your following divs, which you do not want to do, or to add a wrapper div around the svg content, which again ends up adding an extra div which was not there in the first place.
Upto you to make the call how you want to do it.